# can you help if I'm right on how I found the life time of the fossil?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

the question says The half-life of a certain radioactive isotope is approximately $6100$ years. Suppose a fossil is found today to have $0.01\%$ of it’s original amount of this radioactive isotope. How old is
the fossil?
what I did is if i let $X$ to be the initial amount then the half life would be: $$\ln(0.5x/x)=-k6200 \implies k=1.118*10^{-4}$$.
Then i did this: $$\ln(0.0001x/x)=0.000118t$$
which $t=82,379$ years. am I right??

Comment: Seems right to me

Comment: You changed $6100$ into $6200$ and, using $6200$, I get $82,384$ years which is close to your value but not the same.  Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: ow yes my bad thanks

Comment: Since the data say "approximately $6100$ years" you should report your answer as "approximately $82,000$ years". You only know two significant digits.